# How to get coordinates right of a scrolled view with Ionic gesture events?

Tags: html, angularjs, canvas, ionic-framework

I have a HTML canvas overlay with some HTML elements. When I had the view scrolled in a browser (Chrome and iOS Safari), I could not just get the coordinates right. I looked into the event’s centre

> pageX/Y, touches[0]’s clientX/Y, pageX/Y, layerX/Y, screenX/Y

, and various combination of them together, but none of the coordinates seem to reflect the scrolled offset. The browser seems to handle it right, as the drawing using either

> pageX/Y or clientX/Y

were drawn to the scrolled off area and will be displayed once scrolled back.

In the Ionic Github distribution, there is a test case (`test/html/gesture.html`). You can see the same behaviour. Do some dragging in the pink area so it generates quite some contents off the window. Just click at the top of the pink area when scrolled to top and scrolled to bottom,  the Y coordinates would have a quite obvious difference, but they are about the same.

Comment: Are you looking for [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)?

Comment: Thanks to Maximillian for the pointer. Element.scrollTop works with Ionic's test. The "box" element does have the scrollTop attribute changed. However it does not work for my page.  In Ionic test case, "box" element contains a listed of dynamically inserted  <p> elements, while in my case, both canvas and the HTML overlay are part of the container element. The container element has the css position of "relative", while both the canvas and overlay has the css position of "absolute". Maybe that was the reason? The container element's scrollTop is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. With the gesture event `e` (`e.target` is the canvas in my case) :

```
var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = e.gesture.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;
var y = e.gesture.touches[0].clientY - rect.top;
```

Actually `e.gesture.srcEvent.offsetX/Y` would give the coordinates, but `offsetX/Y` not available on iPhone